# I am getting error when i am using rest api angular 2

Tags: angular

**I want to get data using rest api. i am passing my rest api but it showing error**

```
    >      Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
    >     the remote resource at http://ip/JsonServices.php?action=getempdata.
    >     This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
    >     enabling CORS.

        **Below is my code**


  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http ,Response} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class WebserviceProvider {

      constructor(public http: Http) {

        console.log('Hello WebserviceProvider Provider');

      }

     getUser() {


      return this.http.get('http://ip/JsonServices.php?action=getempdata')

        .map((res:Response) => res.json());
      }

    }
```

Any body help me to get resolve above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is cross domain issue.
If rest server and angular server are the same server.
try below.

```
this.http.get('/JsonServices.php?action=getempdata')
```

if "ip" is external server.
The server need to reply response header for CORS

I don't know your server code. but image of fix is below.

```
w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
```

Comment: Yes it is cross domain issue. I am using not my  ip  kindly suggest the above issue

Comment: Kindly  suggest  me where  I will  integrate  above  headers. I am using  php as server  code,  shall I integrate  headers code in php File.?

Comment: yep.you need to replase abobe code in php such as `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`. then put it on top of JsonServices.php

Comment: Great, it's working for me, when i am updated below headers in my php page.. header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');